# How to procure a Schengen visa for a Thai boyfriend

Tags: visas, schengen, russian-citizens, thai-citizens

**Preamble**. I am a Russian engineer and I have had a Thai boyfriend for 9 years now. I live in Russia because there is no good job for me in Thailand (and I find Thai climate too hot for a permanent life). My friend lives in Thailand because Russia is too much risk for a Thai gay boy (to say nothing about climate) and he has to raise two nieces left by his sister who died.

During all these years, I had at least two holidays a year with my boyfriend and as we both love traveling, we've seen most of Asia (Indonesia, Singapore, Malaysia, Myanmar, Laos, Cambodia, Vietnam, Macao, Hong Kong, Korea), some Russia (before there started all this anti-gay hysteria) and once we even got as far as South America (Argentina, Brazil, Chile).

**The point**. Now, my boyfriend is asking me to go to Europe. My saying that Europe is not worth seeing makes no effect, he is eager to go. Obviously, he's seeing too much prettified travelogues on TV.

Traveling to the EU is different because we've never traveled anywhere where my friend would need a visa, and now he does. I have been to Schengen zone only twice in last years because I used every occasion to go to Asia; still, getting a Schengen visa for someone of my occupation and income in the country where I live is a process fairly easy and predictable.

However, I don't know the first thing about how to arrange a visa for my Thai friend. There is no way for us to legalize our union, so legally we are strangers to each other. From the point of view of income, my boyfriend relies on his average-sized rice farm (raising about 10000 USD a year). It is always I who foots the bill when it comes to traveling.

I am quite ready to spend some sum on the scale of 6000 or 7000 USD for a good 3-week trip, but the EU requires a huge amount of expenses (hotel bookings, airline tickets) to be carried *before visa application*, as prerequisites, and if you get refused all this money is essentially confiscated and cannot be recovered because sane air fares and hotel prices are almost always non-refundable. That's what makes me reluctant.

So, **the question**. What's the right course of action? How to procure a Schengen visa for my Thai boyfriend, or at least arrange the application in such a way that even if it is refused, *nothing* is forfeited except the officially-declared visa fee?

*Disclaimer.* I have no particular scruples against bribing or similar things.

Comment: With respect to refundable airfares and hotels, it is always possible to book refundable, wait for the visa, cancel the refundable, and book cheaper non-refundable flights + rooms if the visa was successful.

Comment: @waiwai933 Visa applications cannot be lodged earlier than 3 months before the trip. Optimistically, you get an answer 2½ months before you plan to travel, and that's too late to get any decent price for anything.

Comment: I think there is way too much information in your question, you really only need to supply what passports you have, where you want to go, and for how long.  Your relationship shouldn't really matter, "friends" travel together all the time.  Also it doesn't look too difficult to get a tourist visa for a Thai citizen: http://www.thaiembassy.com/thailand/schengen-visa.php and http://www.siam-legal.com/foreign-visas/schengen-visa-thailand.php

Comment: Two things working in his favor are his ties to Thailand (farm, neices) and his travel history.  In my experience, hotel bookings are generally cancelable up to a couple of weeks before or even the night before, so you mostly need to worry about airfare.  For that, you can make a reservation and then only purchase the ticket after being granted the visa.  I don't know how long a travel agent can hold a reservation without payment, however.

Comment: @phoog As to travel history, it, unfortunately, cannot be proved because his passport was lost in a robbery in Brazil (though he must still have a provisional passport issued in Brasilia). As to hotels, nowadays when you search a booking, you more often than not come across very attractive discounted non-refundable offers (up to 2 times cheaper than refundable ones). I have asked some people in the airline industry about reservations, but they all say that it is not an option these days. The most attractive airfares are offered by airlines who don't sell through agencies.

Comment: @EdmundYeung99 Thank you for links, I'll study them.

Comment: @Che you could submit other documents to support the travel history in lieu of a passport, such as receipts for accommodation or meals.

Comment: @phoog A good idea, thanks. I suppose we have lots of photos. Are they to be added to the application?

Comment: @Che if it asks for information about travel history, then yes.  I would also include the police report for the stolen passport to explain why you're submitting the other evidence instead of it.

Comment: Unless you have some proof that you two are in a relationship, your partner will need to apply with his own proofs of funds. Birth certificates and marriage certificates are usually required when you sponsor someone else.

Comment: @EdmundYeung99 are you connected to the law firm for those links?

Comment: @AyeshK Do you have a reference for that?  Why wouldn't it be possible for two unrelated people to travel together with one paying for the trip?

Comment: It was my experience, actually. I took a trip with my family, with bank statement of my account. They wanted my birth certificate to prove that I'm traveling with my parents and brother.

Comment: @AyeshK, Good insight! I have worked with a lot of  [LDR's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-distance_relationship) including gays and there are some hurdles analogous to those you suggest.  Your comment can be expanded to a helpful answer and I'll almost certainly up vote it.  Please upgrade your comments into an answer.

Comment: @phoog, it is possible for two unrelated people to travel together as partners. [People](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-career_commuter_couples) do it all the time.  You can upgrade your comment to an answer, and if it makes sense I'll happily up vote it and delete mine :)

Answer (score 6):

Based upon what you wrote, you are a Russian national who wants to get a Schengen visa and simultaneously sponsor a Thai national who is not a family member (de facto or otherwise) of yours.  You have a favourable history of performance in Schengen.  Your partner has some travel experience but is unable to prove it.

The gay issue is not really a big deal and Russians can get Schengens at the drop of a hat.  The big issue will be establishing a premise for your partner's visit when there's no 'durable relationship' tying you together (for example, cohabitation, monthly remittances, shared expenses, joint bank accounts, and so on).  So while there may be legal barriers to forming a civil partnership, nothing prevents a committed lifestyle together. **Consular officers will be looking for signs they define as indicators for a "committed lifestyle"**.  Are your bank accounts held jointly for example? (if so, that's a good thing)

To add some extra complexity, you propose to "double down the bet" by gaming the hotel/air booking systems or by having all your evidence based upon cancellable bookings.  They will interpret this evidence as reduced quality and much worse, it may undermine your claim to a committed relationship (that's a bad thing).  But just to take things a step further, even the highest quality, non refundable, prepaid bookings will not save an application where the premise is failed.

**How to procure a Schengen visa for my Thai boyfriend, or at least arrange the application in such a way that even if it is refused, nothing is forfeited except the officially-declared visa fee?**

This question has been answered largely in comments.

1. Have your partner collect the bookings needed to support the
   application making sure that all of them are fully cancellable (or
   gamed);
2. Have your partner include his financial evidence along with an
   authenticated copy of yours;
3. Put together any evidence you have supporting the claim to a de
   facto relationship;
4. Submit the application to a Schengen issuing post in Thailand.  Assuming you apply to the Netherlands, you would apply via their [facilitator, VFS](http://www.vfsglobal.com/netherlands/thailand/index.html).

When the decision is reached, your stated objective will be the result: you have lost the application fee.  Implicitly however, your partner's credibility will be stained going forward (that's a bad thing), and your claim to a de facto relationship will be weakened (that's also a bad thing).

I enjoyed the hint that you are open to bribery.  It tells me that you are devoted and ready to take on some extra expense in order to enjoy a holiday in Europe with your partner.  So where does that leave us? For about 1/3 - 1/2 the price of dealing with the [snakeheads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snakehead_(gang)), you can instruct a blue-blooded, accredited law firm with a practice area in Schengen to represent your partner's application.

**What's the right course of action?**

If you are doubtful about how to best assure your partner's successful application, you can arrange a consultation with a solicitor.  Select a law firm with impeccable credentials in European migration and let them sort it out.

Comment: I always understood that you were not meant to pay for hotels or flights until _after_ your visa was approved.

Comment: I also understood what @MichaelHampton says to be true.  The German site I consulted earlier, for example, said the same (I do not remember which site it was, exactly), and I've seen that advice repeatedly.  But given Che's comments, and my experience several years ago of having a reservation that had to be paid for in one week, I wonder whether this guidance isn't naive or outdated (the people writing the guidance obviously have never applied for Schengen visas, so have probably not tried recently to keep a reservation for tickets or accommodation open for several weeks without paying).

Comment: @phoog, I am doubtful that the application would reach the stage where the decision-maker wanted to examine confirmations.  But can you please convert your comment into an answer? Maybe fleshed out a bit more?

Comment: @GayotFow My comment is more of a question than an answer, don't you think?

Comment: Just out of interest, could you elaborate a bit on "nothing prevents a committed lifestyle together", please? It seems to me that one partner preferring Russian climate and the other partner preferring Thai climate is indeed an obstacle to living physically together and makes pretty much everything connected to it impractical (joint bank accounts when living in different countries? Wouldn't that, for instance, mean that the bank is always a foreign bank for one of the partners and thus invariably lead to increased transfer fees for one of them, thus making this a no-go option?).

Comment: @MichaelHampton I never said there is the requirement to pay for hotels to get the visa (though I know of an occurrence when a Schengen embassy required to do so; from what I heard, it seems as if Central European countries like it this way). But we don't need to just get a visa; we want to do the trip in the first place, which means we need hotel bookings for their own sake not just for the visa. And yet again, for example, in Lapland there are lots of prepaid options which are 50% cheaper than pay-at-hotel ones.

Comment: @GayotFow: I'm a bit confused by your comment, but anyway - I was just trying to point out that it's an unrealistic assumption that people in an international LDR would have joint bank accounts. (After all, it's already an unrealistic assumption that all couples physically living together go through the hassle and join their bank accounts.) As such, I found it questionable to imply joint bank accounts are a sign of a "committed lifestyle together", rather than just plainly stating that joint bank accounts are one of the factors a consular officer may be looking for.

Comment: @GayotFow: Neither do I have any idea what a consular officer would look for, nor did I claim so in any of my comments.

Comment: @GayotFow: I have suggested a modified version of the statement I was referring to that IMHO makes it a bit clearer that "just being oneself" (here: leading what the OP may *feel* to be a committed lifestyle) may not be enough, but that certain extra hurdles may need to be passed in order to actually *prove* the existence of the relationship. Sorry if the purpose of my comments was unclear or confusing.